# Find overlapping/complex circles with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to compute the red circles radius (fig 2). I have troubles finding these circles using HoughCircles from OpenCV. As you can see in fig. 2 I can only find the little circles in center which are shown in black using HoughCircles.

original [image: pic1]  fig 2. [image: red]

Since I know the center of the red circles (which are the same as the red ones), is there a way to compute simply the radius of the red circles ?

Is it also possible to have a generic way of computing radius of circles on a more complex image such as this one :

[image: example 2]

Edit : Here the interesting part of my code after obtaining fig 2 :

```
threshold(maskedImage, maskedImage, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV | THRESH_OTSU);
    std::vector<Vec3f> circles;
// Canny(maskedImage, maskedImage, thresh, thresh * 2, 3);

HoughCircles(maskedImage, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, src_gray.rows / 4, cannyThreshold, accumulatorThreshold, 0, 0);

Mat display = src_display.clone();
for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
{
    Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
    int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    // circle center
    circle(display, center, 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);
    // circle outline
    circle(display, center, radius, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);
}
```

I have tried to use play with cannyThreshold and accumulator without results. Real images are 5x biggers. Here [a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Yv8cvdcD-bRDBsSEJuYTJfdDg/edit?usp=sharing) for example 1 after threshold.

Thanks

Comment: can you show your HoughCircles code? overlapping/halfcircles etc normally aren't a problem for HoughCircles afaik.

Comment: Thank you Micka I just added some code

Comment: Can you save maskedImage to a file (`imwrite("maskedImage.jpg", maskedImage)`) and post a link?

Comment: We need `maskedImage` after the line `threshold(maskedImage, maskedImage, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV | THRESH_OTSU);` not before :)

Comment: Can you fix the link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already know the smaller circles in the image(which you have drawn in black).

- Prepare a mask image using these circles so the areas having smaller circles will have non-zero pixels. We'll call it **mask**:

[image]

- In the original image, fill these circle areas in a dark color(say black). This will result in an image like your fig 2. We'll call it **filled**
- Threshold the **filled** image to obtain the dark areas. We'll call it **binary**. You can use Otsu thresholding for this. Result will look something like this:

[image]

- Take the distance transform of this **binary** image. Use an accurate distance estimation method for this. We'll call this **dist**. It'll look something like this. The colored one is just a heat map for more clarity:

[image]   [image]

- Use the **mask** to obtain the peak regions from **dist**. The max value of each such region should give you the radius of the larger circle. You can also do some processing on these regions to arrive at a more reasonable value for radius rather than just picking up the max.
- For selecting the regions, you can either find the contours of the **mask** and then extract that region from **dist** image, or, since you already know the smaller circles from applying hough-circle transform, prepare a mask from each of those circles and extract that region from **dist** image. I'm not sure if you can calculate max or other stats by giving a mask. Max will definitely work because the rest of the pixels are 0. You might be able calculate the stats of the region if you extract those pixels to another array.

Figures below show such mask and the extracted region from **dist**. For this I get a max around 29 which is consistent with the radius of that circle. Note that the images are not to scale.

mask for a circle, extracted region from **dist**

[image]    [image]

Here's the code (I'm not using hough-circles transform):

```
    Mat im = imread(INPUT_FOLDER_PATH + string("ex1.jpg"));

    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(im, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    Mat bw;
    threshold(gray, bw, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY|CV_THRESH_OTSU);
    // filtering smaller circles: not using hough-circles transform here. 
    // you can replace this part with you hough-circles code.
    vector<int> circles;
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(bw, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
    for(int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0])
    {
        Rect rect = boundingRect(contours[idx]);
        if (abs(1.0 - ((double)rect.width/rect.height) < .1))
        {
            Mat mask = Mat::zeros(im.rows, im.cols, CV_8U);
            drawContours(mask, contours, idx, Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1);
            double area = sum(mask).val[0]/255;
            double rad = (rect.width + rect.height)/4.0;
            double circArea = CV_PI*rad*rad;
            double dif = abs(1.0 - area/circArea);
            if (dif < .5 && rad < 50 && rad > 30)   // restrict the radius
            {
                circles.push_back(idx); // store smaller circle contours
                drawContours(gray, contours, idx, Scalar(0, 0, 0), -1); // fill circles
            }
        }
    }

    threshold(gray, bw, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV|CV_THRESH_OTSU);

    Mat dist, distColor, color;
    distanceTransform(bw, dist, CV_DIST_L2, 5);
    double max;
    Point maxLoc;
    minMaxLoc(dist, NULL, &max);
    dist.convertTo(distColor, CV_8U, 255.0/max);
    applyColorMap(distColor, color, COLORMAP_JET);
    imshow("", color);
    waitKey();

    // extract dist region corresponding to each smaller circle and find max
    for(int idx = 0; idx < (int)circles.size(); idx++)
    {
        Mat masked;
        Mat mask = Mat::zeros(im.rows, im.cols, CV_8U);
        drawContours(mask, contours, circles[idx], Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1);
        dist.copyTo(masked, mask);
        minMaxLoc(masked, NULL, &max, NULL, &maxLoc);
        circle(im, maxLoc, 4, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1);
        circle(im, maxLoc, (int)max, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        cout << "rad: " << max << endl;
    }
    imshow("", im);
    waitKey();
```

Results(scaled):

[image]    [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it's a nice idea. I have obtained the same results you have using distanceTransform. (By the way how do you color the distance map applyColorMap does not seem to work for me). However I don't see how I can differentiate circles radius and compute effectively these maximum values ?

Comment: In OpenCV, distance transform result will be of type float. Try scaling it to 0-255 range and converting to type uint8. Then applyColorMap will work. As for obtaining max values, see my edited post to see if I have answered your question there.

Comment: Thank you for you valuable answer. I got the map color but I have difficulties understanding how I can extract the region using mask images and center of small circles. Could you detail this part please ?

Comment: I added two figures at the end. Use the smaller hough-circles you already have to generate a mask for each such circle. The first image is such a mask, and the second image is the corresponding extracted region from distance-transform image. You can then find the max value of this second image which is the radius of the larger circle. You can repeat this for other circles.

Comment: Thank you very much dhanushka, your code is really helpful and helps me using efficiently OpenCV. I think I will stick with your algorithm but my previous question was silly since I know the small circles centers then their values in the distance map should be approximatively the distance from the closest contour right ? Hence I already had my answer but I am grateful with this nice code. :)

Comment: The center will not give the radius unless it overlaps with the distance max. So it's always better to consider a neighborhood around the center. I  this solution, the neighborhood is the smaller disk.