# Simple circle detection model

Tags: image-processing, language-agnostic, feature-detection

I have a set of 100x100 px photographs of light "spots" on dark background. They look like this:

[image]

As you can see, they are not perfectly centered, the boundary is imperfect, and sometimes there are secondary blemishes. However, the object of interest is always fairly large (>1/10th of the area) and more or less circular.

I want to find the size of each spot.

After picking 100 random pixels from each 100x100 tile I was able to select pixels belonging to spots by calculating the Z-score vs. background, and then keeping only pixels with Z>3. I can then calculate center of mass (with x/y coords and Z as mass) to get an approximation for the center of each spot. However, I'm not sure how to detect their diameter.

I have thought of simply drawing a circle around the outermost bright pixels, then in cases where there are blemishes I will end up with an overly large circle. Clearly I need a model that is better at accommodating false positives (ie. pixels which are bright but do not belong to the spot). Is there a mathematically simple way of doing this (ie. not a complex SVM approach)? The result should be something like this (if we visualize it):

[image]

Comment: Hi Wassinger, this is probably more appropriate for [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) site, which deals with questions on signal and image processing.

Comment: You can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681204/2571705).

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

1. Convert to a binary image by using a threshold
2. Perform an appropriate number of [erosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)) operations to get rid of the blemishes or at least separate them from the spots
3. Perform the same number of [dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)) operations to restore the original size of the spots.
4. for each region of connected white pixels, calculate the centroid and count the number of pixels to estimate the radius.
5. Ignore regions with too few pixels.

You could add additional checks to make sure a region is approximately circular. For example you could check if the distance between each boundary pixel and the centroid lies within a certain range.

Comment: Excellent simple solution.